# Using REGEX with Sql Statement

Tags: php, sql, regex

I'm wanting to check if in my column named "tag" it contains numbers with two digit numbers using Regex.

my query:

```
$FilterTag="3,2,11"
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bTown = ? AND REGEXP_LIKE(tag, '.*[$FilterTag]')";
```

My table:
[db table tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFOR.jpg)

the only problem is that my query is finding single character numbers ,like instead of telling me that it contains 11 it will tell me that it contains 1.

Is there any way that i can group a character set of numbers?

Comment: Are 3, 2 and 11 specifically the only numbers you're trying to match?

Comment: i'm wanting to match numbers from 1 to 99

Comment: The regex for that would be the one Enissay posted. Removed mine because it matches 0-99; I missed that you didn't want 0 included.

Comment: What DB are you using? Can you show what data your currently have and what you should and shouldn't get? Maybe make a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not clear!

So you want to get entries with tag having `3` AND `2` AND `11`.

You'll have to split your string/filter `3,2,11`, then generate the condition using a loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bTown = ?";

foreach (explode(",", $FilterTag) as $value)
    $sql .= " AND REGEXP_LIKE(tag, '\b$value\b')";
```

which should produce the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bTown = ? 
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(tag, '\b3\b')
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(tag, '\b2\b')
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(tag, '\b11\b')
```

**Extras:**

To allow only numbers from 1 to 99, use this regex:

```
\b[1-9][0-9]?\b
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/tA9rT9/1)

To allow two digits numbers (with leading zeros for numbers <10) use:

```
\b(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/tA9rT9/2)

Comment: what i'm wanting is to compare a set of numbers, the $FilterTag string will be different each time and i want to match those numbers in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Returns all records with 2 digits.

```
select * from table1
where tag REGEXP ('^[0-9]{2}$');
```